# problem with charging symbol,

Tags: charging

I purchased a unlocked Samsung Galaxy 3 mini from the internet. Worked fine until I went abroad and change the SIM card. Now I am back in the UK, I am having trouble charging the phone.

The charging symbol remains on the screen after charging and sometimes it indicates its charging. When I remove the charger, the phone has not been charged. I can get the phone to charge and remove the charge symbol buy removing the battery and rebooting.

Will a reset fix this problem? I'm running android 4.1.2

Comment: Not sure if it *will*; but assuming it's a software issue, it *should* (if you are talking about a factory-reset, that is − a hard-reset obviously didn't fix it as you've already done so by removing the battery).

Comment: It seems unlikely to be a software issue. More likely there's a short in the micro USB connector: it's worth blowing at it and inspecting it with a magnifying glass.

Comment: It could be the charger not putting out enough power, the IPhone had a similar problem actually when you use a non-genuine Apple charger in the UK. Are you using a genuine Samsung charger? Are you using a wall USB adapter?